# Prove that a group scheme over a field is separated.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

How to prove that a group scheme over a field is separated, i.e. to show that the unit $e:\mathrm{Spec}(K)\to G$ is a closed immersion.

Comment: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/047J

Comment: I have seen that proof and I think it is wrong.

Comment: You cannot deduce from Morphisms Lemma 19.2 that the image of $e$ is a closed point.

Comment: You need the fact that for a morphism $f\colon X\to Y$ a section $s\colon Y\to X$ maps closed points to closed points. I think that's what they quote there.